# Extension of Data Processing Inequality: If $X \rightarrow Z \rightarrow Y$, $I(X, ZY) \geq I(X, Y)$?

Tags: it.information-theory

If we have the Markov chain $X \rightarrow Z \rightarrow Y$, we can say $I(X, Z) \geq I(X, Y)$ from the data processing inequality. Then, can we say that $I(X, ZY) \geq I(X, Y)$?

Comment: What does $ZY$ mean? Multiplication of two random variables?

Comment: If so, consider $Y = 1/Z$.